# How could I convert an instance of a parent class to one of its subclass in python?

Tags: python, oop, python-imaging-library

I am pretty new to python, and I ran into a bit of trouble while playing around with `PIL`. I had written:

```
from PIL import Image

class FImage(Image.Image):
    def foo(self):
```

I was using the `Image.open()` function to intialize an image, but I didn't know how to convert that into an instance of `FImage`. Is this doable? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Just an edit to clear something up, the `Image` in `Image.open()` refers to a `.py` file, not the class itself.

Comment: What new behavior does the subclass implement, that the conversion is desirable?

Comment: I think you should be able to call parent `open()` method using your FImage instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `open()` is a function of the `Image` module and not a method of the `Image.Image` class, you cannot just override it and have it return an FImage instead.

However, you could define an `open()` function in your own FImage module and instead of inheriting from `Image.Image` (which would also mean implementing its abstract methods), you could just encapsulate an `Image.Image` instance and pass any references you can't deal with to it:

```
from PIL import Image


class FImage:
    def __init__(self, img: Image.Image):
        self._img = img

    def foo(self):
        print(f'Hello foo, from {type(self)}')

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._img, attr)


def open(*args, **kwargs):
    return FImage(Image.open(*args, **kwargs))


# calling your open, not Image.open directly, passing all parameters
fimg = open('test.png')

# just showing the resulting fimg is an FImage, with all Image functionality
size = 16, 16
fimg.thumbnail(size)
fimg.save("test.icon.png", "PNG")

# but also any FImage functionality
fimg.foo()
```

By the way, if you're not looking to replace a reference to the `Image` module with a reference to your own `FImage` (?) module, I would very much suggest changing the name of the replacement `open()` function, since `open` shadows the built-in function. Pillow shouldn't have used that to begin with... Perhaps `fopen()`?

Note that the `FImage` in my proposed solution isn't technically an `Image.Image`. You could decide to inherit anyway, but then you'd have to implement the abstract methods as well.

In the end, it's a bit of a design flaw in the Pillow module, in my opinion. If they had made `open()` a class method of the `Image` class, you would be able to override it and more easily create an `Image` descendant. It would appear the authors of Pillow prefer you don't create descendants, for whatever reason.